# SSH remote forward success but test from remote site not working

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

Took me a while to figure this out, but finally got remote port forwarding to work with **ssh** as follows:

```
ssh -N -i /etc/ssh/id_rsa user@somewhere.com -R 8080:localhost:80 -C -v
```

The local server uses a private key to connect to the remote server which has a public key configured. Able to authenticate successfully, no errors in the log. The last line that ssh prints is:

```
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 8080, connect localhost:80
```

I tried testing this from my **public site**, as follows:

- http://www.somewhere.com
- http://www.somewhere.com:8080
- https://www.somewhere.com
- https://www.somewhere.com:8080

However, nothing happens - still see this line:

```
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 8080, connect localhost:80
```

If I **test locally** on the **remote server using http://127.0.0.1:8080**, it **works** fine.

**NOTE: The following is set in sshd_config on the remote server:**

1. AllowTcpForwarding yes
2. GatewayPorts yes

Not sure what I am missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from `man ssh`

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only.This may be overridden by specifying a
> bind_address.  An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.  Specify‐
> ing a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

Comment: Thanks, this was already enabled in sshd_config. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I checked my sshd_config again and between restoring VM's and stuff, looks like I forgot to redo this step.